# ora-03147 missing mandatory TTC field

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have oracle 12c r2 and developer12c when I connect to database in report builder I get this error: ora-03147 missing mandatory TTC field

[image: image error]

Comment: [According to this link](https://www.oraexcel.com/oracle-11gR2-ORA-03147) this is caused because a corrupt Two-Task Common (TTC) packet was received. This is an internal protocol error. You should contact Oracle Support Services.

Comment: please any help

Comment: Befor run report bulider copy file (tnsnames.ora)
from path:
C:\Oracle\Database\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
to path:
C:\Oracle\Middlewar\user_projects\domains\InfoSys\config\fmwconfig

Comment: I reproduced this error in my environment in the Reports Builder with a locked account, a user without connect privilege, and wrong password. These situations gives the same error that has nothing to do with the real reason!
I used Oracle 11g 11.2.0.4, Forms 12.2.1.3, Windows 2012 r2 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle support [has a response](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=239387524357542&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2391464.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=w0v82f02l_4)
(you'll need to sign up to read in full
Document id is Doc ID 2391464.1, if the link fails ...).

In brief, one cause can be unescaped "$" signs in the the password passed to Oracle Reports.
Meanwhile I'm getting the same error, where there's no funny characters in my password (passed as URL parameters). So the Oracle Support comment is not the full answer.

As for tnsnames.ora being identical: not an issue in my situation.

I hope to advise in more detail...

Answer (score 0):

I had this message pop up while running and Oracle report, I eventually found it was caused by trying to populate a number placeholder with characters

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32881532)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).